# How to get SocketCAN access inside LXC container?

Tags: arm, lxc, socket, container

I have an LXC container on an ARM processor using the Yocto toolchain. I have Ethernet working, but I am unable to get SocketCAN access inside the container.

Outside the container SocketCAN works fine, but I need it inside the container.

How can I get SocketCAN to work inside an LXC container?

Or maybe a better way to ask is, how can I add a CAN interface to an LXC container?